# Esvaziar múltiplas tabelas numa única execução

Tags: php, php-5, pdo

Via [**`PDO`**](http://pt1.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.pdo.php), consigo fazer o [**`TRUNCATE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> de uma tabela da seguinte forma:

```php
// Matriz de definições
$dbcon_new = array(
  "host"     => "localhost",
  "dbname"   => "bubu",
  "username" => "super_dragon",
  "password" => "balls"
);

// estabelece a ligação
$dbh = new PDO(
  'mysql:host='.$dbcon_new['host'].';dbname='.$dbcon_new['dbname'].';',
  $dbcon_new['username'],
  $dbcon_new['password'],
  array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT               => false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE                  => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND       => "SET NAMES utf8"
  )
);

// esvazia a tabela xpto
$dbh->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE xpto");
```

## Pergunta

Como posso numa única execução realizar o `TRUNCATE` a múltiplas tabelas?

Comment: @GabrielGartz Alterei a frase da secção de pergunta que havias editado pois ficou mesmo estranho (pelo menos para um Português de Portugal).

Comment: Sim, agora está mais claro, eu falo Português do Brasil e estava com dificuldade de compreender a pergunta por isso tinha editado, mas desta maneira ficou clara em ambos dialetos. :)

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a própria sintaxe do `TRUNCATE` na [documentação do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html), isso não é possível. O que você pode fazer é passar diversos comandos de `TRUNCATE` na mesma query, separados por ponto-e-virgula:

```
TRUNCATE tabela1; TRUNCATE tabela2; TRUNCATE tabela3; --etc...
```

Apenas se atente à ordem das tabelas para não limpar antes tabelas das quais outras tabelas dependem.

Answer (score 0):

Não tem como você executar um `truncate` para várias tabelas, até porque podem existir triggers diferentes e respostas diferentes para cada tabela e não teria como a base de dados testar os comandos depois validar em todos e te retornar o ocorrido no final.

O que você pode fazer é ter vários comandos de `truncate` no mesmo exec:

```
$dbh->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE xpto; TRUNCATE TABLE xpty;");
```

Ou executar um loop para executar várias vezes até terminar a operação:

```
$arr = array('xpto', 'xpty');
foreach ($arr as $table) {
    $dbh->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE $table;");
}
```

Sendo que a segunda opção é mais aconselhável, pois na primeira se ocorrer uma falha durante o `truncate`, os próximos comandos poderão ser ignorados dependendo da engine da base de dados em uso.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo usar o `DELETE`ao inves do `TRUCANTE` pois nao é possivel dar [TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) em tabelas que possuem chaves estrangeiras(FK)

passe um array($tabelas).

```
function deleteTabela($tabelas){

    $db = new PDO();

    forach($tabelas as $item){
        $item = limparEntrada($item);
        $sql  = "DELETE FROM $item";
        $db->query($sql);
    }

}
```

Comment: Na verdade é possível dar o `TRUNCATE`, desde que não haja entradas na tabela com chaves estrangeiras, correto?